# Why my regex isn't working for date?

Tags: java, regex, date

I've got a problem using a regex to match the date in a string. Actually I've got a lot of "date formats" to match but the first one doesn't work and I don't get why it wouldn't work...

The format is like "September 12, 2013" or "May 6, 2014" or "June 02, 2014"...

In my string **text**, there is the following date : "July 4, 2014".

Here's my code :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+ [0-3]?[0-9], (1|2)\\d{3}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

But it comes to this error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match found
```

I even tried with smaller regex but it still doesn't match anything.

Thank you in advance for the help !

Comment: You didn't call `find` or `matches` method

Comment: you need to use find function.

Comment: Don't use a regex to check a date: there are too many edge cases (for example leap years and September 1752). Instead, attempt a parse and handle any exceptions.

Comment: I suspect that you are misunderstanding what `group(x)` means. Could you explain what result you expect from `m.group(1)`?

Comment: @anubhava @Avunash Raj Thank you, it helped me understanding the problem ^^
@Bathsheba Can you explain me in further details ? ^^
@Pshemo I understand now, it prints me the first match circled with `()` ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke `Matcher#find()` or `Matcher#matches()` before invoking `Matcher#group`.

Otherwise, the match is not performed, hence you have neither the whole group, nor any single back-references populated.

Both methods mentioned above return `boolean`, which will help you infer whether or not your desired group will contain any text.

A typical idiom would be:

```
if (matcher.find()) {
    // get the group(s)
}
```

Documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

On the other hand, I would recommend you use `DateFormat`s instead of regular expressions for dates - API [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, 

I tried to match with Pattern.matches but it returned false. I even tried with the regex "may" (I found this 3 times in my text) but false as well.

Actually I want to find the first date in a String, with a list of date formats I've got, and I wanted to use regex for that, can DateFormat help me find the date in my String ?

Comment: @Malik `System.out.println(Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+ [0-3]?[0-9], (1|2)\\d{3}", "September 12, 2013"));` returns `true`. Check your input text.

Comment: I think I understood why I got it wrong, the date is **contained** in the String, it's not the String itself, that's why it returned false

Comment: Thank you, so I tested `if (m.find()) {
     System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }` and it returns `2`, do you know what's the meaning ?

Comment: @Malik it means your captured group indexed at `1`, that is, `(1|2)` returned `2`, as expected.

Comment: I answered to myself by searching, I just circled my regex with (), which printed "July 4, 2014" as expected ! Thank you for the help and sorry for such stupid questions... ^^'

So how should I improve it, I want to get the first occurence date from different strings, and all those strings have different formats (and different languages), I'd have used several regex but it's quite inconvenient, can `DateFormat` be more convenient ?

Comment: @Malik `DateFormat` **are** the way to parse dates!

Comment: I can't find how to **extract** a date in any format, from a String.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `if(m.find())` and print `m.group(0)` because if you print `m.group(1)` this will print 1 or 2, `(1|2)` according to your input, as your input has 2014, `m.group(1)` will print 2. And `m.group(0)` means the first group of  `"[a-zA-Z]+ [0-3]?[0-9], (1|2)\\d{3}"` and it prints your full text because it takes your full regex as a first group because there is no other group except `(1|2)`.

Try this code.

```
String text="July 4, 2014";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]+ [0-3]?[0-9], (1|2)\\d{3}", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
if (m.find( )) {
    System.out.println(m.group(0));
}else{
    System.out.println("No match found");
}
```

**Output**

*July 4, 2014*

Visit [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm) to know basic with example

Answer (score 0):

You need to condition for m.find() and print m.group(0) in place of (1).

```
    String text = "July 4, 2014";
    String pattern = "\\b(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|Jun(?:e)?|Jul(?:y)?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|(Nov|Dec)(?:ember)?)\\D [0-9]{1,2}, [0-9]{4}";

    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    Matcher m = r.matcher(text);
    if(m.find()){
    System.out.println("Found value: " + m.group(0));
    }
```